# Как заполнить формы на сайте текстовыми данными, которые у меня в программе, но не делать запрос

Tags: java, html, парсер

Имеются текстовые данные на компе. Мне нужно вбить их в поля на сайте, просто написать их в эти поля, без сохранения , т.е. на сервер сайта никакие запросы не отправляются. Так же на сайте есть поле spinner, после того как я вписываю туда текст, предстоит еще выбрать его кликнуть на него в spinner. Какие есть способы это сделать с наименьшими затратами, чтобы ноуту не пришлось перегружать страницу?
 Я думал править html страницы, для этого я должен находить в кеше браузера данные открытой html и не факт что он мне даст его править, пока он открыт в браузере, а если и даст то придется перезагружать html. А это не годится. Наверняка есть способы которые позволяют заполнять формы. Подскажите в какую сторону копать.
Может использовать что нибудь использующее другой язык? php ..

Comment: Вы хотите это сделать с самом браузере, я правильно вас понял?

Comment: Да,  я хочу сделать это в браузере. Так как есть сайт, для которого писать отдельно программу с формами мне не хочется, хотя если сделать это, то было бы легко вставить текст.  У меня есть два сайта. Мне с одного надо перенести текст в поля (EditText так скажем) другого, просто написать туда текст, но не отправлять, не сохранять. Проблема в том что вручную копировать каждое поле и вставлять на другом сайте это долго. Поэтому я написал парсер , но теперь думаю как сделать, чтобы это сразу вставлялось в открытую в браузере страничку.

Comment: Я понимаю, что html код странички содержит input поля. Мне интересно  смогу ли я эти поля заполнить, чтобы они сразу же отобразились, ну или хотя бы после перезагрузки страницы.

Answer (score 1):

**1 вариант. Написать расширение для браузера.**

Статья с примером написания расширения для Chrome - [Расширения для Google Chrome. Часть первая. Getting started](https://habrahabr.ru/post/133776/).

Минусом является то что для всех браузеров свои стандарты расширений.

**2 вариант. Использовать расширения Tampermonkey.**

Это браузерное расширения позволяет создавать пользовательские JavaScript скрипты для браузеров. Из плюсов что работает под основными ведущими браузерами.

http://tampermonkey.net

Comment: У меня недавно был вопрос о том как сделать уведомление, что на странице появилась новая заявка. Мне сказали писать расширение. Но решил без этого: просто парсю страницу и при появлении там заявки, уведомляю. Думаю, в данном случае тоже можно обойтись без расширения. Тем более расширение вроде пишется на Javascript, а он  из браузера не имеет доступа за пределы текущей страницы, на которой он запущен. А тот текст , который я хочу поместить в поля на сайте находится в переменных моего приложения на Java. Максимум могу записать их на жесткий диск, но смысл? Javascript к ним не подступится.

Comment: @Turalllb По идее браузер не должен давать сторонним программам возможность изменять что-то на страницах. Если бы такая возможность была, это была бы уязвимость, которую можно использовать для воровства паролей например. На счёт того к чему имеют доступ расширения, как я понял они могут запускать внешние программы, подробнее сказать не могу.

Comment: @Turalllb расширения могут 100% брать данные с внешних сервисов, можно настроить на локальном компьютере так, что бы он по определённому адресу выдавал в виде json ответ, а расширение берёт этот ответ. Да, сложно, но при отсутствие других вариантов...

Comment: Ведь браузер позволяет мне заполнить поле "комментарий" ? Почему это он не позволит программе?

Comment: @Turalllb потому что это потенциальная уязвимость и какая-то вредоносная программа на компьютере сможет например прочитать ввод пароля на сайте.

Comment: @Turalllbя не утверждаю, но предполагаю, а так может и есть какая-то возможность повлиять на браузер, может API есть для этого.

Comment: Дмитрий Полянин, я попробовал пройти авторизацию с помощью jsoup на этом сайте. Хотел создать свою форму как на этом сайте, в которые я буду вставлять данные, чтобы сохранить их после проверки. Ну задача состояла в том, чтобы авторизоваться и узнать какой запрос сохраняет все поля.  Оказалось, сайт выполняет очень много яваскриптов, авторизоваться вроде как смог, но не факт что сайт имеет какой то запрос, в котором передаются данные со всех форм, для сохранения. Наверно многое выполняется в скриптах. Хотя с другой стороны, сервер ведь должен узнать , что я вписал в поля.

Comment: Данные как то да должны сохраняться. Но сайт для меня очень сложный. Кажется придется пытаться написать расширение. Я попробовал в html страницы через хром вписать текст. Все отображается.

Comment: Вопрос решил с помощью webDriver . Автоматизацией ввода данных в поля.  Есть минусы, но было для меня проще чем заниматься расширением